# when i write str1 it is writing a different shape

Tags: c

It is working but for example when i write str1 it should be "we" but it is not write this in true way.instead of that it is writing a different shape.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
       char str1[10], str2[10], str3[10];
       int year;
       FILE* fp;

       fp = fopen("a.txt", "w+") == NULL;
       fputs("We are in 2012", fp);

       rewind(fp);
       //fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", str1, str2, str3, &year);
       fscanf(fp, "%s", str1);

       printf("Read String1 |%s|\n", str1);
       //printf("Read String2 |%s|\n", str2);
       //printf("Read String3 |%s|\n", str3);
       //printf("Read Integer |%d|\n", year);
       
       system("pause");
       return(0);
}
```

Comment: remove the ==NULL part

Comment: While you are inexperienced, you should avoid compound expressions because you will get them wrong too often.  When you are more skilled, you should definitely avoid compound expressions because they make debugging more difficult.  When you are an expert, you will not need to be told to avoid compound expressions:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
fp = fopen("a.txt", "w+") == NULL;
```

will assign the result of the comparision to `fp`.

Remove the `== NULL` to assign the file pointer returned by `fopen()` itself.

```c
fp = fopen("a.txt", "w+");
```

After that, you should check if `fp` is not `NULL` using an `if` statement.

```c
if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
}
```